# Java 1.8 installation on MacOS X 10.9 - missing JavaVM link

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running MacOS 10.9.  A while ago I upgraded to Java 1.8, and in the process had to rebuild the links in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework (because I screwed up).

I ended up with this symlink:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

That enabled me to run java from the command line.

Now I want to run Eclipse.  I installed it but it won't start up; it gets this error:

```
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/JavaVM
```

So I think I need a symlink "JavaVM" pointing somewhere in the jdk1.8.0_31.jdk directory structure, but I can't figure out where.

Thanks much for any help..

Comment: Please ask clear question and improve question title.

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.7 so I don't know if this helps but mine looks like... JavaVM -> Versions/Current/JavaVM

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question, possibly post this Q over on apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a VM info like `java version "1.8.0_31"` when running `java -version` from your shell and assuming you have eclipse unpacked in your `Applications` folder you could try the following:

- Go to `Applications` > `Eclipse` folder.
- Right click `eclipse` and select `Show Package Contents`.
- Go to `Contents` > `MacOS` folder.
- Edit `eclipse.ini` file with your favorite text editor.
- Search for the *-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion* key under -vmargs and set it to *1.8*, like so:

  **-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8**
- Save it and try opening eclipse again.

In my environment, besides installing it normally using the Java installer, I also have the following in my ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Comment: No change.  I think the problem is that a file (link) called JavaVM must exist in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/, but I inadvertently deleted it when I installed 1.8...what is the contents of your /System.../Versions/A directory?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer. If you're still in trouble with this symlink, can't you clean up your environment and try reinstalling it?

Comment: /System, as I understand it, is where MacOS is installed...so yes, I could reinstall MacOS...maybe that's the answer.

Comment: /System, as I understand it, is where MacOS is installed.  Yes, I could re-install MacOS...maybe that's the answer.  Thanks!  PS - I can't tell from your screenshot whether the contents are files or links...and if links, where they point.

Answer (score 1):

in eclipse go to preferences. then go to Java -> Build Path -> Installed JREs. then click search on the right hand side and it should be there. Make sure the one you want is clicked. 
I had the same problem before too.

Comment: Thanks...but Eclipse doesn't even start; I can't go to preferences.  I've updated the question, hopefully it's more clear.